# R: At What Depth Should the Parallel Call Be In

Tags: r, parallel-processing, complexity-theory, computer-science, computation-theory

I have a nested `*apply` calls and I want to parallelize them.  I have the option to parallelize on either the top call or the nested inner call.  I believe that, in theory, the first one is supposed to be better, but my problem is that I have 4 cores but the outer-most object has 5 parts that are of *very* varying sizes.  When I ran the first example, all 4 cores ran for about 10 minutes before 2 of them finished.  At 1 hour the third one finished, and the 4th was the last one to finish at 1:45 having gotten the two largest processes.

What are the pro's and con's of each?

```
parLapply(cl, object, function(obj) lapply(obj, funct))

-- OR --

lapply(object, function(obj) parLapply(cl, obj, funct))
```

Additionally, is there is a way to manually distribute the load?  That way I could separate the two large objects and put the two smallest together.

EDIT: Generally, what does CS theory state about this situation? Which is generally the best place for a parallel call (excluding peculiar circumstances like this)

Answer (score 0):

`parLapply` groups your tasks so there is one group of tasks per cluster worker. That doesn't work well if you need load balancing, so I suggest that you try `clusterApplyLB` instead:

```
clusterApplyLB(cl, object, function(obj) lapply(obj, funct))
```

If you have 5 tasks and 4 workers, this will schedule tasks 1-4 on workers 1-4, and then it will schedule task 5 on the worker that finishes it's task first. That may work reasonably well, but it will work better if the last task is the shortest.

If instead you use:

```
lapply(object, function(obj) clusterApplyLB(cl, obj, funct))
```

it will execute 5 separate parallel jobs. That could be very inefficient if the tasks within those parallel jobs are small, plus you will waste resources for each of the 5 jobs that have load balancing problems. Thus, this approach doesn't usually work well.

You usually want to use the first case, but load balancing is often a serious problem when the number of tasks isn't much larger than the number of workers. If each call to `funct` takes a reasonable amount of time (at least a couple of seconds, for example), you could try unrolling the loop using the nesting operator from the foreach package:

```
r <-
  foreach(obj=object) %:%
    foreach(o=obj) %dopar% {
      funct(o)
    }
```

This turns all of the calls to `funct` into a single stream of tasks, but still returns the results in a list of lists.

You can find out more about using the foreach nesting operator in a vignette that I wrote called [Nesting Foreach Loops](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/nested.pdf).

Comment: the problem with `clusterApplyNB` is that my list doesn't have dimentions and so I can't put in a margin value.

Comment: @Adam `clusterApplyLB` takes exactly the same arguments as `parLapply`, and they are functionally equivalent. Both of them are basically parallel versions of `lapply`. The main difference between them is that `parLapply` groups the tasks in much the same way that `mclapply` does and `clusterApplyLB` performs load balancing. Neither `clusterApplyLB` or `parLapply` operate on matrices or arrays.